# How do you loop through a field on a custom engine in refinery cms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms, refinery

I'm creating a [custom engine](http://railscasts.com/episodes/333-extending-refinery-cms?view=asciicast) in [refinery cms](http://refinerycms.com/) and I have a field called "PDF" that is a refinery [resource field type](http://refinerycms.com/guides/multiple-resources-in-an-extension).

Some entries in the engine will only have one pdf, while others will have multiple pdf's. Is there a way to do this without creating a bunch of extra fields that I don't need?

I'd prefer to loop through one pdf field rather than code extra fields into my engine - pdf_1:resource, pdf_2:resource, pdf_3:resource, pdf_4:resource, pdf_5:resource, etc.

How would you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge there isn't a built-in Refinery process for this. `has_many` would be the way I would approach the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Would this be the right approach?

Create a new model for the pdf that belongs to my_custom_engine and use my_custom_engine has_many pdfs. Then use accepts_nested_attributes and some javascript on the admin view to add photos to each my_custom_engine entry. Pretty much like this:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised?autoplay=true

I guess that's basic rails stuff, but I wanted to make sure there's not a way to do this built into refinery already.